# When will be the attributes of Spark API Respone updated?

Tags: apache-spark

When I hit the api, "http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications", I am getting the below response

```
[ {
  "id" : "app-20231102170315-0320",
  "name" : "context1698924794012",
  "attempts" : [ {
    "startTime" : "2023-11-02T11:33:14.253GMT",
    "endTime" : "1969-12-31T23:59:59.999GMT",
    "lastUpdated" : "2023-11-02T11:33:14.253GMT",
    "duration" : 8996421,
    "sparkUser" : "user",
    "completed" : false,
    "appSparkVersion" : "3.4.0",
    "startTimeEpoch" : 1698924794253,
    "endTimeEpoch" : -1,
    "lastUpdatedEpoch" : 1698924794253
  } ]
} ]
```

As much I observed, lastUpdatedEpoch attribute always same as startTimeEpoch. When will be lastUpdatedEpoch attribute updated ?

Also, is it possible to update that attribute from my own spark listener ?